# Adding product programatically in a new module

Tags: magento2, product

Here is my requirement.
1. I have a new module page that has "Add to Cart" button. This module calculates the price for the product. Once the user clicks on Add to Cart button (new button that I have added on this page), I want to add this product to my cart with custom price. 
2. I had a working code (Magento 2.0); now that I am on 2.1; my code no longer work.
3. I browsed thorugh google and people said I should use CartRepositoryInterface instead of ObjectManager but I don't know how. Whenever I try to add this class in __construct, my code gives error saying it does not expect these classes.

Here is my code that I have written to add product to cart:

```
<?php
namespace Silver\Customize\Controller\addProduct;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Registry;

class addProduct extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $pageFactory;
    protected $registry;
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry)
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {        
        $this->registry->register('var_sku', $this->getRequest()->getParam('arg_sku'));
        $this->registry->register('var_new_price', $this->getRequest()->getParam('new_price'));

        $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();
        $this->addProductToCart();
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');

    }    

    public function addProductToCart()
    {

        $om         =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product =   $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $product->load($product->getIdBySku($this->registry->registry('var_sku')));
        $price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('new_price'); // Replace price with your price
        $cart = $om->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

        $qty=1;
        $quote = $cart->getQuote();
        $quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
        $quoteItem->setCustomPrice(5000);
        $quote->save();
        $cart->setQuote($quote);
        $cart->save(); -- FAILS HERE
        $message = __('You added customized %1 to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());

        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
    }

}
```

When I run this code, I get an error as "Cart 82 does not contain item 157". Can anyone help me please?

Comment: By the way, my code works if I login and try... please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You should follow exact validation and procedure like magento.
So please go to this file and check written code for Add to cart:
Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add.php